# can't make the background of a div visible on top of two other divs

Tags: html, css

i want the "slideshow" and "destination" divs to have the colored backgrounds on top f the "mainheader" "maincontent" and "content" divs. but the background is not visible. here is my code. The text in the slideshow and destination divs is visible but the background is not.

**HTML**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title> 
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <header class="mainheader">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="#" alt=""/><h1>HEADER</h1>
        </a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>blank</li>
                <li>blank</li>
                <li>blank</li>
                <li>blank</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </header><!--mainheader-->
        <div class="maincontent">
             <div name="slideshow">
                <img sr ="#" alt=""/><h2>Slideshow</h2>
             </div><!--slideshow-->
             <div name="destinations">
                 <h2>Destinations</h2>
             <div><!--destination-->
        </div><!--maincontent-->
    </div> <!--CONTENT-->

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    align-content: center;
    margin: 0px;
}
.content {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: brown;
}
.mainheader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #4949bf;
    align-self: center;
}

.mainheader nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}
.maincontent {
    background-image: url(img/transparent.png);
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-top: -10%;
}
.slideshow {
    box-shadow: green;
    width: 70px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
.destinations {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;

}
```

Comment: Would be a good idea to also include some markup with your CSS

Comment: i didn't think it was necessary. included it now. thanks.

Comment: Looks like a couple of typos to me.  Does the markup accurately reflect your environment?  `<div><!--destination-->` should be `</div><!--destination-->` and you have CSS class styles for `.destinations` and `.slideshow` but those elements use the `name` attribute instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is incorrect. Instead of `class` you have used `name`. Change these lines `<div name="slideshow"> <div name="destinations">` like this `<div class="slideshow"> <div class="destinations">`.

And change `box-shadow` to `background-color`

```
.slideshow {
    box-shadow: green;
```

like this

```
.slideshow {
    background-color: green;
```

Comment: On a side note you should use div.slideshow and div.destinations in your CSS. This is good practice.

Comment: @mcphersonjr Interesting.  What's the rationale for that being a good practice?  I would think just the opposite considering minification and that `.slideshow` is less likely to be reused on any other non-div element.

Comment: oh gosh. i make such silly mistakes. thanks for taking out time and pointing it out.

Comment: @JosephMarikle You would be correct in assuming that the use of "slideshow" would normally be less likely to be used on any other non-div element. However the user decided to use a class instead of an id, which by nature constitutes the ability and intention to use the "slideshow" class in multiple elements. With this in mind it is "good practice" to denote the element when defining a class in CSS so that your definition is as specific as possible to the element with class and not the class of any element.

Comment: @mcphersonjr A valid point, but I think I disagree.  I would consider `div.whatever` to have unnecessarily high specificity and ID's I avoid altogether for styling unless I'm intentionally creating an imbalance in specificity.  [This article](http://oli.jp/2011/ids/) summarizes a few problems with using ID's.  If unique classes are used, then it becomes superfluous to increase the specificity with the element name.